# Migrate Websphere Portal 6.1.x theme to version 7

Tags: themes, websphere, portal, websphere-portal

Does anybody know where I can find information on migrating a custom theme from version 6.1.5 to version 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information regarding that topic in the [portal wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf).

Your migration path depends on what kind of theme you were using. In 6.1.5 there was an old theme and page builder theme. I guess with custom theme you are refering to the old theme that was available in 6.0.x and 6.1.x..

For the old themes created with the RAD check: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Migrating_themes_wp7

For the old pagebuilder theme check: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Moving_a_mashup_theme_to_the_new_architecture_wp7

Comment: Is there a way to just transfer the theme to a new server?  I'm not actually migrating the environment, just transfering components.

Comment: Do you have your theme in a seperate EAR or is it still part of your wps.ear?

Comment: It's still part of the wps.ear.

Comment: There was a guide on that in the portal wiki as well. You basically copy the theme dependend file out of the wps.ear into a separate EAR/WAR. You deploy that new file and register the theme. Unfortunately may old link on the wiki doesn't work anymore.